# How to achieve retry mechanism for Mule SFTP outbound-end point for one-way MEP

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Can any one help me out in achieving   retry mechanism for Mule SFTP outbound-end point for one-way MEP .

Answer (score 0):

Reconnection strategy is configured on the SFTP connector: it reconnects the connector and inbound endpoints.

Outbound endpoints are automatically reconnected.

If you are asking about retrying outbound operations in case of failure, you have two options:

- If the inbound endpoint of the flow can perform redeliveries (JMS, AMQP...), use this mechanism to trigger retries of the whole flow that contains the SFTP outbound,
- Otherwise wrap the outbound SFTP with `until-successful`: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. Sorry i was wrong with re-connection, i was looking for a retry mechanism for sftp outbound end one way.In mule sftp transport mechanism  documentation it was mentioned it sftp doesn't support retry. I was looking for any alternative approach to achieve it.

Comment: Then I've extended my answer :)